# Insertar fecha en Oracle desde php

Tags: php, oracle

consulto porque tengo días con este error en Oracle ORA-01843 mes no valido, bueno les comento que tengo un campo date en mi HTML que me devuelve el siguiente valor:

```
    $Fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
  
    $newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $_POST['fecha'])->format("d/m/Y");

    var_dump( $Fech,$newDate);

 resultados de var_dump
   
  string(10) "2022-12-28"
  string(10) "28/12/2022"
```

En la base de datos hay fechas con el formato 28/12/2022, pero cuando la ejecuto dice Oracle ORA-01843 mes no valido

```
 $sql->bindParam(':FECHA', $newDate);
```

Que estoy haciendo mal, soy nueva en oracle y no comprendo porqué dice ese error según leí hay que poner to_date para formatear la fecha así que intenté:

```
$sql->bindParam(':FECHA', to_date($newDate));
```

Alguien me puede dar una luz de como hacer el insert llevo varios días tratando el problema pero no dpy con la solución, gracias por cualquier ayuda brindada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el campo es DATE, Oracle no aceptará de buenas a primeras una cadena como fecha. Debes convertirlo antes a [Objeto de Fecha](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+to_date) de Oracle.

Entonces, en tu consulta, iría algo como:

```php
$consulta = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES (..., TO_DATE(:FECHA,'YYYY-MM-DD'), ...)";
// ...
$sql->bindParam(':FECHA', $_POST['fecha']);
```